# Can't import modules in Python 3

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have a layout like

```
pylib/
    apps/
        main.py
    libs/
        MyClass.py
    __init__.py
```

In which `MyClass.py` is

```py
class MyClass:
    pass


if __name__ == "__name__":
    obj = MyClass()
```

and in `main.py` I've tried

```py
from pylib.libs.MyClass import MyClass
obj = MyClass()
```

And got

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylib'

```py
from ..libs.MyClass import MyClass
obj = MyClass()
```

And got

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

```py
from libs.MyClass import MyClass
obj = MyClass()
```

And got

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs'

If someone knows how to fix it I'd be very glad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: Dis you install your module or add it to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Note that since there is no ˋpylib/__init__.pyˋ, ˋpylibˋ is a namespace package. This is likely not intentional. Either use ˋlibˋ directly, or add an ˋ__init__.pyˋ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the folder that contains `pylib` is not on the path.  You can fix this by adding the containing folder to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

```
➜  apps  python3 main.py        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pylib.libs.MyClass import MyClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylib'
➜  apps  cd ..
➜  pylib  cd ..
➜  temp-code  export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`  # This is the fix!
➜  apps  python3 main.py        
(no error)
```

Another way you could do it is to include the logic in your code:

```
import os
import sys

project_home = '/home/username/temp-code/'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path
```

In this case, the `pylib` folder is inside of the `temp-code` folder and this code runs before you import your class.

Hope that helps!

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH